# Splitting columns to 2 combinations format in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe formatted like this:

```
A  B  C  D 
----------
x1 x2 x3 x4
y1 y2 y3 y4
```

and i want to get every 2 combination of columns below each other like

```
S  T 
-----
x1 x2
y1 y2
x1 x3
y1 y3
x1 x4
y1 y4
x2 x3
y2 y3
...
x3 x4
y3 y4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `combn`

```
do.call(rbind, combn(seq_along(df), 2, FUN = 
         function(x) cbind(df[,x[1]], df[,x[2]]), simplify = FALSE))
#     [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "x1" "x2"
# [2,] "y1" "y2"
# [3,] "x1" "x3"
# [4,] "y1" "y3"
# [5,] "x1" "x4"
# [6,] "y1" "y4"
# [7,] "x2" "x3"
# [8,] "y2" "y3"
# [9,] "x2" "x4"
#[10,] "y2" "y4"
#[11,] "x3" "x4"
#[12,] "y3" "y4"
```

---

Or more compactly

```
data.table::rbindlist(combn(df, 2, simplify = FALSE))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("x1", "y1"), B = c("x2", "y2"), C = c("x3", 
 "y3"), D = c("x4", "y4")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2"))
```